# Unable to extract the text using Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, extract

Please help in identifying what is wrong here. I tried using below given Xpath's but no luck. Please see the image.

1. I tried using the custom xpath -

`xpath("//*[@class=' js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths']/body/div[@class='ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable']/div[@class='ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle']/span[@class='ui-dialog-title']").getText`

This one returns element not found error. However the object is identified when this Xpath is given in Selenium IDE

2. id("ui-id-8").getText  - This one returns blank

[image: [HTML of the page]]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it readable.  Also, never use images for code or markup; always use text formatted as code.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi..Sorry..I am not so familiar with stack over flow. Hence did not know how to format it properly.

Comment: Did you check the help center page on [**How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Hi..Thanks for sharing the link. But do they allow HTML tags? I went thru the link and saw that only few tags are allowed. Or is there any other way to share the HTML?

Comment: Reduce the problem to a [mcve] and include the reduced HTML directly in your question, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to use xpath as per the html given in screenshot. (Highlighted span element's id is 'ui-id-7', but you have used 'ui-id-8' in second point, which is a empty UL.

First point xpath you are searching for 'ui-dialog-title' where it should be 'ui-dialog-titlebar'. But the xpath you are trying is too cumbersome and may not be correct.

For you to get the text in the title bar, following code snippet should help:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-id-7']")).getText();
```

Comment: Hi..Looks like there was a change in the HTML after the latest code deployment.Yesterday it was ui-id-8. Sorry for the confusion though.